# v-bind:class not working with array variables

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following code in vue-js:

```html
    <table class="table table-sm user-perm-list">
      <tbody v-for="index in totalUsers" v-bind:key="index">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="text-medium">{{userPermissionsName[index-1]}} </div>
            <div class="d-flex py-1">
              <a 
                 style="cursor:pointer; margin-right:0.4rem" 
                 @click=userPermissionsDownloadClicked(index-1) 
                 :title="userPermissionsDownload[index-1] ? 'Download Permitted':'Download not permitted'"
                 v-bind:class="[userPermissionsDownload[index-1] ? 'permission-icon-class-active' : 'permission-icon-class-inactive']">
                <downloadPermissionIcon/>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

the v-bind:class inside "a" tag is not working. Inside `userPermissionsDownloadClicked`, I am toggling the variable: `userPermissionsDownload[index-1]`. It works with a non array variable but not working with array variable

Comment: Can you post the data you have for your `totalUsers` variable?

Comment: Do you mean to have a new `<tbody>` for every element in `totalUsers`? I would expect the `v-for` directive to exist on the `<tr>` element in this case.

Comment: Can you show an example of an object in the `userPermissionsName` array? That along with the `totalUsers` variable will help us know where the problem lies

Comment: Is the title updating correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the "Vue Gotchas"

https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/

From "Why isn’t the DOM updating?"

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).